# Help with replacing image placeholders in matrix rows -- using Stash?

Tags: matrix, stash, mx-jumper, shortcode

I have some legacy code that was using **mx_jumper** successfully. On updating to EE 2.11.2 the code no longer works.

The context is a Matrix field with rows including:

- A text field called `{item_desc}`
- An Assets field called `{item_img}`, containing 0, one or more images

Each Matrix row instance of `{item_desc}` may include **placeholder text** referring to an image in `{item_img}`. For example, in a placeholder such as `{img_3_1}`, 3 is the **row count** and 1 is the **image count** within the Assets field.

My legacy snippet, running within each Matrix row, has code including this…

```
{item_img}
    {exp:mx_jumper:put name="img_{row_count}_{count}"}
    <figure{if item_img_align} class="{item_img_align}"{/if}>
      <img src="{url}" alt="{alt_text}">
      {if caption}<figcaption{if keywords} class="{keywords}"{/if}>{caption}</figcaption>{/if}
    </figure>
    {/exp:mx_jumper:put}
{/item_img}

{exp:mx_jumper:out_global}
    {item_desc}
{/exp:mx_jumper:out_global}
```

But on EE 2.11.2 this no longer works.

I can't figure a way to use quotes or wrapping `{}` within the mx_jumper name parameter to get it to play ball.

But I'm sure there's a better way to do this using **Stash**.

I've had a look at Mark Croxton's [Replacing matrix image slugs into another field](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Replacing-matrix-image-slugs-into-another-field) but I can't figure how to adapt it for my above context.

I'm aware of inefficiencies within my old approach, but at this point I just need to get it working again without having to change content.

Any help much appreciated.

*My above code has been updated to correct errors made when originally posted.*

Answer (score 0):

Robin Sowell of EllisLab pointed me to the solution, via a ticket, which was to move `exp:mx_jumper:out_global` out of the snippet into the embed that was calling it.

Converting the above approach to Stash can wait for another day.